# Open in Safari with UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm sharing a URL via UIActivityViewController. I'd like to see "Open in Safari" or "Open in browser" appear on the share sheet, but it doesn't. Is there a way to make this happen?

Note: I am not interested in solutions that involve adding somebody else's library to my app. I want to understand how to do this, not just get it to happen.

Comment: Can you show your current code that shows a `UIActivityViewController`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could add your custom action to Share sheet in iOS

You would have to copy this class.

```
class MyActivity: UIActivity {
    var _activityTitle: String
    var _activityImage: UIImage?
    var activityItems = [Any]()
    var action: ([Any]) -> Void
    
    init(title: String, image: UIImage?, performAction: @escaping ([Any]) -> Void) {
        _activityTitle = title
        _activityImage = image
        action = performAction
        super.init()
    }
    override var activityTitle: String? {
        return _activityTitle
    }

    override var activityImage: UIImage? {
        return _activityImage
    }
    override var activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType {
        return UIActivity.ActivityType(rawValue: "com.someUnique.identifier")
    }

    override class var activityCategory: UIActivity.Category {
        return .action
    }
    override func canPerform(withActivityItems activityItems: [Any]) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    override func prepare(withActivityItems activityItems: [Any]) {
        self.activityItems = activityItems
    }
    override func perform() {
        action(activityItems)
        activityDidFinish(true)
    }
}
```

Please go through the class you might need to change a few things.

This is how you use it.

```
    let customItem = MyActivity(title: "Open in Safari", image: UIImage(systemName: "safari")  ) { sharedItems in
        guard let url = sharedItems[0] as? URL else { return }
        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
    }

    let items = [URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!]
    let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: [customItem])
    ac.excludedActivityTypes = [.postToFacebook]
    present(ac, animated: true)
```

I have done this for one action, and tested it, it works.

Similarly you could do it for other custom actions.

For more on it refer this link.
[Link To Detailed Post](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/118/uiactivityviewcontroller-by-example)